# xsi:schemaLocation with multiple values using org.w3c

Tags: xml, xsd, kml

i am trying to append multiple values to  schemaLocation attribute:

```
Document document = null;
        Element documentElement = null;
        final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance();
        Element root = null;
        try {
            final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            document = builder.newDocument();

            root = document.createElement("kml");
            document.appendChild(root);
            documentElement = document.createElement("Document");
            final Element topNameElement = document.createElement("name");
            documentElement.appendChild(topNameElement);
            root.appendChild(documentElement);

            root.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/","xmlns:xsi",
                "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            root.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0");
            root.setAttribute("xmlns:ar", "http://schemas.opengis.net/arml/2.0");
            root.setAttribute("xsi:schemaLocation", "http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0  http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd    http://schemas.opengis.net/arml/2.0     http://schemas.opengis.net/arml/2.0/arml.xsd");
```

however, the results are :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0" xmlns:ar="http://schemas.opengis.net/arml/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0  http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd &#9;http://schemas.opengis.net/arml/2.0 &#9;http://schemas.opengis.net/arml/2.0/arml.xsd">
<kml>

</kml>
```

how did i add multiple values removing the 	 encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a whitespace character. In your code you are using additional whitespace between the schemaLocation entries. Try reducing that to one space every time.